# How to periodically estimate states of a LTI if the output is measured irregularly?

Tags: control, sensor-fusion

How can I periodically estimate the states of a discrete [linear time-invariant system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory) in the form $$\dot{\vec{x}}=\textbf{A}\vec{x}+\textbf{B}\vec{u}$$ 
$$\vec{y}=\textbf{C}\vec{x}+\textbf{D}\vec{u} $$if the measurements of its output $y$ are performed in irregular intervals? (suppose the input can always be measured).

---

My initial approach was to design a [Luenberger observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer) using estimates $\hat{\textbf{A}}$, $\hat{\textbf{B}}$, $\hat{\textbf{C}}$ and $\hat{\textbf{D}}$ of the abovementioned matrices, and then update it periodically every $T_s$ seconds according the following rule:

> If there has been a measurement of $y$ since the last update: $$\dot{\hat{x}}=\hat{\textbf{A}}\hat{x}+\hat{\textbf{B}}\hat{u}+\textbf{L}(y_{measured}-\hat{\textbf{C}}\hat{x})$$
>   If not:
>   $$\dot{x}=\hat{\textbf{A}}\hat{x}+\hat{\textbf{B}}\hat{u}$$

(I have omitted the superscript arrows for clarity)

I believe that there may be a better way to do this, since I'm updating the observer using an outdated measurement of $y$ (which is outdated by $T_s$ seconds in the worst case).

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer or commenting on incorrect answers. This helps new users find the information they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be conveniently addressed in the context of multi-rate Kalman estimation.

See for example "[Multi-rate Kalman filtering for the data fusion of displacement and acceleration response measurements in dynamic system monitoring](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/223050722_Multi-rate_Kalman_filtering_for_the_data_fusion_of_displacement_and_acceleration_response_measurements_in_dynamic_system_monitoring)" (Section 4).

Essentially, you have to establish a time sample $T_s$ lower than the minimum time interval you can expect from two consecutive measurements. Then, you always perform the Kalman time update step each $T_s$ instant, whereas the measurement update is run only upon fresh data.